# swipe UIView to the side and make him disappear - ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to swipe some UIView from center to left or to right, but after the edge I want to make the view to disappear. The swipe should be tracked by the place of the holding finger, and after the finger slipped the view to right or left side the view should fly to the side who he slipped to, but if the view doesn't slipped i want him to return to his place that he were.

I tried to use UIPanGestureRecognizer on my UIView

My custom UIView is artistDetailsView

```
var panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanFrom:")
self.artistDetailsView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
```

That was in the viewDidLoad() function

```
func handlePanFrom(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation: CGPoint = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view)
    let velocity: CGPoint = recognizer.velocityInView(recognizer.view)
    print(translation)
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

    }
    else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed {
        //track the movement
    }

    else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        //animate to final position
    }
}
```

About my custom view
The view bounds all the screen
which means that the wight of my custom view and the ViewController is equal.
When the view slipped left, the right side of the view should be after the left side of the ViewController and disappear, when the view slipped right the left side should be after the right side of the ViewController and disappear.

The problem is that I don't know what to do in every each state of the UIPanGestureRecognizer.

I'll be glad if someone will help me about that!

Answer (score 0):

```
[secondViewController.view setFrame:rect]; //Where Rect is the current screen size 
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
// move this page to the right:
[timeLinePaneController.view setFrame: swipeRightRect];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {


}];
```

This is the code to swipe to right and load a background page.

Comment: it's fine... I understand objective-c too, but I rather swift.
About the answer, it is not enough for me. I need to swipe the view ,for example to the right ,and I need the view to move where my finger moves it,
and when I flick the view to the right I want that the view will fly after the left side of the view controller with animation.